# Inducer motor cycles on and off after AC Unit has cooled house to requested temp

Tags: hvac

My Carrier unit inducer motor cycles on and off after the AC unit shuts off.  We unplugged drain hole in condenser box but it is still happening. AC unit runs, blower works and house is cooled just fine.

Comment: My Carrier unit inducer motor cycles on and off after the AC unit shuts off.  Carrier #58STA/STX. AC unit will run, blower blows and house cools to requested temp. AC shuts off and blower blows for the 90 seconds, then all is quiet. Then a couple of minutes later the Fan in the inducer motor comes on for several seconds then shuts off. I had the panel off and saw it. The yellow light blinked what looked like 2 fast and 1 or 2 long but that code referenced heating issues? One other issue was a small pool of water under the furnace. My son unplugged a clogged drain in condenser box

Comment: See the 'Edit' button up there?